# How to get FFTW working

Tags: c, eclipse, fftw

I am having problems getting FFTW 3.3 to work on my system.I downloaded the files from the fftw.org website, and then followed the installation instructions which told me to go to the terminal and type

```
./Configure
make
```

and everything seemed OK, but when I try and use FFTW in my C code by using the `include<fft3>` statement I get the fatal error

```
fatal error: 'fftw3.h' file not found
```

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

My IDE: Eclipse, My System: OSX 10.8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
./configure
make
make install
```

You forgot the install command.