# Getting fftw.h working in C

Tags: c, compiler-errors, header-files, fftw

I downloaded the fftw package from [fftw.org](http://www.fftw.org) and, per the instructions, ran the installation commands

```
./configure
make
make install
```

When I try to compile the file fastfoo.c:

```
#include <fftw.h>

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following error:

```
fastfoo.c:1:10: fatal error: 'fftw.h' file not found
#include <fftw.h>
         ^
1 error generated.
```

A similar question was posted a while back ([How to get FFTW working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19742069/how-to-get-fftw-working)) where the poster forgot the "make install" command, however I am still getting the same error.

Another set of instructions said to run

```
sudo make install
```

which I tried, but, alas, to no avail.

I feel like this is the cooking equivalent of not being able to boil water...

Comment: Where did `make install` put `fftw.h`, and is it in your include path?

Comment: Not sure, when I ran `make install`, the path it appears to be throwing stuff in is  `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin`. Also, when searching in finder there are no `fftw.h` files found.

Comment: So I found `fftw3.h` in the directory `Macintosh HD/usr/local/include`. Is this where it should be?

Comment: Assuming you are trying to build against version 3, you should be using `#include <fftw3.h>` (instead of `#include <fftw.h>`)

Comment: I get the same error when using `#include <fftw3.h>`.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally use `pkg-config` to set the required flags:

```
$ find /usr/local -name fftw\*.pc
/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig/fftw3.pc
$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig
$ pkg-config --cflags --libs fftw3
-I/usr/local/include  -L/usr/local/lib -lfftw3  
$ export CFLAGS="`pkg-config --cflags --libs fftw3` $CFLAGS"
```

And at this point you may discover that the `*.h` is actually not what you wrote:

```
$ find /usr/local -name fftw\*.h
/usr/local/include/fftw3.h
```

so the `*.c` file may need adjustment:

```
$ cat fff.c
#include <fftw3.h>

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
$ make fff
cc -I/usr/local/include  -L/usr/local/lib -lfftw3       fff.c   -o fff
$ ./fff
$
```